# How do I use HttpClient in Java to retrieve a binary file?

Tags: java, httpclient

At the moment I can retrieve a text page as follows

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(
            "http://google.com");

    try {


        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);


        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Suppose get is targeted at a binary file.  How would I save this correctly to disk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just don't go via a `Reader` - read the data from the `InputStream` and write to an `OutputStream`.

```
// Using Guava (guava-libraries.googlecode.com)
InputStream data = response.getEntity().getContent();
try {
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    try {
        ByteStreams.copy(data, output);
    } finally {
        Closeables.closeQuietly(output);
    }
} finally {
}
```

Comment: I get an error The method copy(InputSupplier<? extends InputStream>, File) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (InputStream, File)