# Read a text file from web in Android

Tags: android, file

As part of my project I want to read an online text file that contain a url say(www.example.com/download.html).

The text file we can access via (www.example.com/url.txt).

I want to read the content of text file and want to store that in a string. Someone please help me on this. Tried [Read text file from server in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641565/read-text-file-from-server-in-android-app) method but not working.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is there an error? A crash? Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: Are you getting this exception `NetworkOnMainThreadException` ? Have u added this permission in manifest : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: It is not reading the text file from the server. Added the permission on manifest.

Comment: What errors are you getting ? instead of reading from .txt file try reading using json

Comment: try {
     url = new URL("http://www.example.com/update.txt");
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
     urlString = in.readLine();
     in.close();
 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
 } catch (IOException e) {
 }
This is the code for reading...

Comment: The entire code
http://pastebin.com/vFumNZLA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the HttpResponce code you got from the http request to be 200?

Comment: `code`
try {
     url = new URL("http://www.example.com/update.txt");
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
     urlString = in.readLine();
     in.close();
 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
 } catch (IOException e) {
 }

The text file have only one line and that is a url.

Comment: I consider using Apache HttpClient class a much standard approad for fetching data over the web. The primary advantage I see is that the responce codes give a lot better idea about what is happening. You can have a bunch of things going on like redirects, access not allowed, certificate related errors. [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)

Comment: I dont have much idea about java programming. This is a part of my project so I'm just learning from web according to my requirement. If you can give me an example that will be great. Hope you now understand my needs from the whole code.

Comment: Sure. This should help you[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660243/how-do-i-use-httpclient-in-java-to-retrieve-a-binary-file). If you are not able to read still, add the following line before getting the BufferedReader which says: httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(). This will tell you the standard response code which you can compare against [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html)

Comment: Thanks will test it and let you know... :)

Comment: And what does logcat say? You must be seeing an exception log. I see that you are calling this in onCreate() which is called on the main thread. You need to spawn another thread and always do network operations on the background thread.

Comment: I got the solution and it is working...have to do that in AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create a Thread to handle this request. In most versions Android OS forbids doing network requests in the main thread.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391272/how-to-use-separate-thread-to-perform-http-requests)