# How to read binary data serialized via Avro using HTTP as transport?

Tags: java, http, serialization, deserialization, avro

I'm using Avro as the serialization protocol. My service is ready, every serialization/deserialization works fine in memory.
So now I'd like to test it to see if it works fine after HTTP transport.
I thought it's simple to write a method to test, but after a while, I'm not able to figure it out, here's what I've tried:

1. Using HttpClient:

   ```
       String itemIds = "abc123";
       System.out.println("itemIds are: " + itemIds + "\n\n\n");
       String endpoint = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/items?itemIds=" + URLEncoder.encode(itemIds, "UTF-8");
       HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
       HttpGet request = new HttpGet(endpoint);
       String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";    
       request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
       request.addHeader("Content-Type", "avro/binary");
       HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
       System.out.println("Response Code : "
           + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
       byte[] bytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
       SearchMaterializationDto deserializedReponse = SearchMaterializationAvroObjectSerializer.deserializeToSearchMaterialization(bytes);
       System.out.println(deserializedReponse.toString());
   ```

This approach is throwing java.io.EOFException. when executing this line `SearchMaterializationDto deserializedReponse = SearchMaterializationAvroObjectSerializer.deserializeToSearchMaterialization(bytes);`

Here's my `SearchMaterializationDto deserializedReponse = SearchMaterializationAvroObjectSerializer.deserializeToSearchMaterialization(bytes);` method:

```
public static SearchMaterializationDto deserializeToSearchMaterialization(byte[] buffer) {
        SearchMaterializationDto searchMaterializationDto = new SearchMaterializationDto();
        try {
            ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
            searchMaterializationDto.readExternal(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return searchMaterializationDto;
    }
```

And here's my SearchMaterializationDto.java class (listed only the invoked method):

```
@org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
public class SearchMaterializationDto extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
private static final org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader
    READER$ = new org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader(SCHEMA$);

  @Override public void readExternal(java.io.ObjectInput in)
    throws java.io.IOException {
    READER$.read(this, SpecificData.getDecoder(in));
  }
}
```

2. Using Avro Decoder as this [example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AVRO/FAQ) shows:

   ```
   private static void decoderWay(String endpoint) throws IOException {
   byte[] bytes = getBytes(endpoint);
   Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(bytes, null);
   SpecificDatumReader<SearchMaterializationDto> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<SearchMaterializationDto>(SearchMaterializationDto.getClassSchema());
   SearchMaterializationDto searchMaterializationDto = reader.read(null, decoder);
   }
   ```

But it's also throwing EOFException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.ensureBounds(BinaryDecoder.java:473)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readLong(BinaryDecoder.java:160)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.doReadItemCount(BinaryDecoder.java:363)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readMapStart(BinaryDecoder.java:408)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ValidatingDecoder.readMapStart(ValidatingDecoder.java:211)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readMap(GenericDatumReader.java:308)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:177)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:116)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:230)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:144)
```

Comment: Looks like the deserializer is trying to read more bytes while the HTTP stream has already ended. Is there a variant that would accept an `InputStreamReader`? Also: is `avro/binary` really the correct MIME type?

Comment: `avro/binary` is the correct MIME type per [avro doc](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#HTTP+as+Transport) I'm not entirely understanding what you mean `Is there a variant that would accept an InputStreamReader`, could you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: That MIME type is an abomination. Regarding the `InputStreamReader`: I think the deserializer is not assessing the length of the stream correctly. `response.getEntity().getContent()` would return an `InputStream` that may assist in this. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660243/how-do-i-use-httpclient-in-java-to-retrieve-a-binary-file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be my serialization/deserilization code problem. I've changed it to the following and it works:

```
public static byte[] serializeSearchMaterializationToByteArray(SearchMaterializationDto searchMaterializationDto) {
        return avroSerialize(SearchMaterializationDto.class, searchMaterializationDto);
    }

public static <T> byte[] avroSerialize(Class<T> clazz, Object object) {
    byte[] ret = null;
    try {
        if (object == null || !(object instanceof SpecificRecord)) {
            return null;
        }

        T record = (T) object;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Encoder e = EncoderFactory.get().directBinaryEncoder(out, null);
        SpecificDatumWriter<T> w = new SpecificDatumWriter<T>(clazz);
        w.write(record, e);
        e.flush();
        ret = out.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    return ret;
}

public static SearchMaterializationDto deserializeToSearchMaterialization(byte[] avroBytes) {
    return avroDeserialize(avroBytes, SearchMaterializationDto.class, SearchMaterializationDto.getClassSchema());
}

public static <T> T avroDeserialize(byte[] avroBytes, Class<T> clazz, Schema schema) {
    T ret = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(avroBytes);
        Decoder d = DecoderFactory.get().directBinaryDecoder(in, null);
        SpecificDatumReader<T> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<T>(clazz);
        ret = reader.read(null, d);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    return ret;
}
```